# Apache Tomcat по адресу моего .war открывает что-то другое

Tags: java, apache, servlet, maven, tomcat

Установил Apache Tomcat(8.0.30), в Intellij Idea(15.0.2) создал и собрал через maven проект из одного простенького сервлета:

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("<H1>Test</H1>");
    }
}
```

Положил свой test.war в `TOMCAT_DIRECTORY/webapps` и пытаюсь открыть через браузер(предварительно запустив Tomcat) `localhost:8080/library` и у меня появляется на экране надпись `Hello World!`, хотя я передаю совсем другой текст. По какой причине это может происходить?

P.S.Более того, я открыл исходный код открываемой страницы, он соответствует результату работы одного из сервлетов, которые расположены в папке examples.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведи структуру проекта и содержимое `web.xml`

Comment: Добавил и то, и то

Comment: У тебя по маппингу сервлета нужно на "/library" обращаться.

Comment: если быть точнее, то `localhost:8080/test/library`, `localhost:8080/test` тебя направляет на `index.jsp`

Comment: Так там по умолчанию корневой контекст дается же

Comment: Корневой , начиная от приложения, а не от сервера. Корневой адрес твоего приложения `localhost:8080/test` (по умолчанию соответствует имени war'ника)

Comment: по умолчанию для всех мейвен артефактов контекстом веб приложения является имя артефакта, поэтому логичнее всего было бы проверять 
  localhost:8080/<${project.artifactId}>/library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В web.xml указан неверный маппинг сервлета. То есть при обращении на /test у вас как раз и открывается другая страница. Нужно обращаться на имя севлета плюс "/library".

Comment: Исправил, не помогло